# WMIC Temp Probe not printing to file

Tags: windows, wmic

I'm trying to retrieve system temperatures using WMIC and print results to a text file

`wmic /namespace:\\root\Win32_TemperatureProbe\MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature > "C:\Users\ethan\Desktop\info.txt"`

I got the syntax for this command from another answer

`wmic /namespace:\\root\WMI path MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature`

Is my command incorrectly formatted or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: What happens when you try the command without redirecting it to a text file. Does it work then? When I run it on my system, I get nothing output from the command, and if there is no output then there is nothing to put in the text file.

Comment: @KenWhite I get a syntax error, but once i added the file redirect the error went away so i assumed there's was something wrong with what i was calling and not necessarily syntax.

Comment: If you get a syntax error running the command iwthout the redirection, the command isn't working. You need to fix that so that it produces the proper output, and then worry about whether you can get it into a file or not. You can't drive your car to work before you fix your car so that it runs, and you can't start trying to save the output of something to a file until that something is working to produce that output. Walk before you try to run. :-)

Comment: Maybe `wmic /namespace:\\root\CIMV2 path Win32_TemperatureProbe`? Add `get /Value` for better _human_ readability, or add `get /FORMAT:CSV` for next _computer_ handling.

Comment: @JosefZ this was the solution. thank you. just needed the `CIMV2`

Answer (score 0):

User `@Josef7` solved this in the comments.

Maybe wmic /namespace:\root\CIMV2 path Win32_TemperatureProbe? Add get /Value for better human readability, or add get /FORMAT:CSV for next computer handling.